# custom edit file Upload field

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have create a custom edit field in manage customer in admin html and also have created a field in database table customer_entity attribute name is Upload_Logo_Cst. but now when i am storing the value in it by admin side then the entered value does not store in Upload_Logo_Cst. pla help me with the appropriate solutions...

```
$fieldset->addField('customer_entity/Upload_Logo_Cst', 'File', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Upload Logo'),
            'name'  => 'uploadlogo',
            'id'    => 'uploadlogo',


        ));
```